# Having trouble installing ubuntu on desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, uefi

**First, my specs :**

- Graphic card : nvidia GTX 960
- Processor : Intel core i5 4570 @ 3.20 GHz
- MB : Gigabyte z87x-d3h
- Ram : 8 GB DDR3 @ 1600
- 2 disks, one SSD with windows 10 installed, the other with windows 10 (both UEFI 64 bit), different version, also installed (have not yet formated the SSD, plan to have Ubuntu on this disk)

**Secondly, the error I'm getting :**

Whenever I go to "Try Ubuntu (or Install Ubuntu)" and hit enter (this is booting UEFI), I encounter an Ubuntu logo after the screen goes white and if I wait a minute or two, the screen goes black and I get what seems to be error messages.

[image: My error message]

Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) if I try booting multiple times, I end up on the same screen. And I've tried waiting a while afterwards (30 mins, I'm booting from a disc) and nothing changes.

Sorry for not formatting this prompt correctly, I have no idea how to add a new line (tried \n) that knowledge would also be helpful. If you need any other info, ask and I will attempt to provide it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would help but....

Have you tried booting from a USB? you can download and format the iso on the USB.

Link to USB site [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

You have not said if the "try ubuntu" option is working? Personally I would start with a tried and trusted version of Ubuntu LTS like Trusty as 16.04 is a bit new and untested.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Log into your account in the TTY.
2. Run sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
3. Run sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa and then sudo apt-get update.
4. Run sudo apt-get install nvidia-364.
5. Reboot
```

If you can't get past the login screen, Ctrl+Alt+F1, reboot and disable UEFI secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with drivers config in Ubuntu.
You need to change drivers configuration in Ubuntu.
Try the following steps:

1. Search for and launch “Additional Drivers” utility from Unity Dash.
2. When it opens, you can see a list of recommended drivers for your graphics cards:
   [image]
3. Install NVIDIA proprietary driver from terminal:

   `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`
4. After installed graphics drivers, re-launch Additional Drivers utility and apply new installed drivers.

Apply Changes by restarting the system.